# jQuery: If span contains any of these words, add this class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've searched for hours, and can't believe I couldn't find the answer to this anywhere.

We have a chat room. Here's the HTML structure for that:

```
<p class="foo"><span>Irene says:</span> some words</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Joe says:</span> some other words</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Billie Jean says:</span> something else</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Gumby says:</span> Well, this is a boring conversation.</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Newbie says:</span> where am i?</p>
```

What I want to do is add the same class to all the `<span>` tags that contain a staff name, and only when they are inside the `.foo` class, so I can make these names stand out in the chat room. I can make it work for one name:

```
$('.foo span:contains('+ Billie Jean +')').addClass('colorize');
```

Can I use that same function with an array?

```
var staffers=new Array(
    "Billie Jean",
    "Joe",
    "Gumby"
);
```

It works for one name if I put 0, 1, or 2 in the [ ] below:

```
$('.foo span:contains('+ staffers[0] +')').addClass('colorize');
```

I thought I could change that to `[i]`, but of course, that didn't work.

I can make fully responsive layouts with pure HTML and CSS, but I don't know more than a few basic javascript functions, and have to look up every little thing I'm trying to do. I don't expect to need this for more than 5 or 6 names, so using a separate `:contains` line for each name can be an option, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Someone had posted a solution here that didn't quite work, but once I removed the `if` part, it worked.

```
for ( i = 0; i < staffers.length; i++ ) {
    $('.foo span:contains('+ staffers[i] +')').addClass('colorize');
}
```

There was also something about the `i` being incremental, but I don't remember what was said.

Whoever you were, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this method is faster then re-querying the dom in the loop

```
var staffers=[
        "Billie Jean",
        "Joe",
        "Gumby"
    ];

var elems = $('.foo span');
elems.each(function (){
    var el = $(this);

    staffers.forEach(function (item){
        if (el.text().indexOf(item) > -1) {
            el.addClass('colorize');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Gabe. Is that better than the code in my OP edit?

Comment: Code without explanation is almost always not very helpful.

Comment: Just added some tomments to my post

Comment: Thanks for the added comments. I take that as a yes, that it's more efficient than the `for` code. Unfortunately, I can't seem to get that to work. Is there a typo somewhere?

Comment: I just edited my code. try that. I was using each instead of forEach

Answer (score 0):

In pure ECMA5 javascript, no library.

CSS

```
.colorize {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<p class="foo"><span>Irene says:</span> some words</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Joe says:</span> some other words</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Billie Jean says:</span> something else</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Gumby says:</span> Well, this is a boring conversation.</p>
<p class="foo"><span>Newbie says:</span> where am i?</p>
```

Javascript

```
var staffers = [
    "Billie Jean",
    "Joe",
    "Gumby"];

// Find all spans contained within elements that have a class of `foo`, step through them all.
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.foo span'), function (span) {
    // Store the text of the span for testing the content
    var spanText = span.textContent;

    // For the current span, step though some of the staffers names until matched.
    staffers.some(function (staff) {
        // Is the name contained in the text?
        if (spanText.indexOf(staff) !== -1) {
            // Yes. Add the `colorize` class to the current span.
            span.classList.add('colorize');
            // We found a match, no need to continue searching staffers.
            return true;
        }

        // Current staff name was not matched. Continue searching staffers
        return false;
    });
});
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EH2sD/)